# how to append data to an xml file using jdom and java

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I was wondering if someone could help append data to an XML file. Below, I have code where it grabs data from another xml file, does some logic changing, and writes the changes to a new output file. However, looking through this [api](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/XMLOutputter.html)

I`m having trouble understanding which method does appending. It seems like all of them creates a new XML file doc/overwrites an existing one if it exists. I`m trying to append tags to the new file as I loop.

```
        for(int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++){

            //get the specific item node 
            Element item = (Element)itemList.get(i);

            //there are some non item nodes so need this check
            if(item.getName().equals("item")){  

                //do some logic changing to the tags

                //System.out.println(item.getValue());
                //System.out.println(item.getChild("Q").getValue());
                //System.out.println(item.getChild("A").getValue());

                boolean exists = (new File("/Users/davidyu/Desktop/file2.xml")).exists();
                //if file exists
                if(exists){
                    System.out.println("in here1");
                    xmlOutput.?????
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("in here2");
                    xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("/Users/davidyu/Desktop/file2.xml"));
                }

            }
```

What I`m basically trying to do, is write a new item tag into the file after every loop iteration. That item tag should contain the new childNodes "Q" and "A".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Given that you're doing this in a loop, it would make sense to load the file *once* before the start of the loop, then go through the loop and add elements to the document as you go, then save it again after the loop. If the file doesn't exist beforehand, create a new document (just in memory, as you'll save it later) with whatever structure you need - e.g. just an appropriate root element. You'll need to work out where you want to add your new elements, of course.

There's no simple way of adding elements to an existing XML file *without* first loading the existing file. (While you could *potentially* do it in a streaming fashion, that's likely to be much more complicated to code.)

Answer (score 0):

XMLOutputter just outputs an existing XML structure to a destination - in your case a File. It seems to me that you are interested in altering the structure of an existing XML document. If that is the case, then once you have a reference to the element that you want want to add content to ( `Element item = (Element)itemList.get(i);` in your example ), you need to do something like :

```
Element newElement = new Element("NewElement");
item.addContent(newElement);
```

This will add the element `<NewElement/>` under the `item` element giving

```
<item>
     <NewElement/>
</item>
```

See the [Element](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs.1.1/org/jdom/Element.html) javadocs.